# run set role command from python on oracle DB

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to below role on an oracle DB from python

`Set role role_name identified by XYZ`

The code which I tried is:

```
self._connection = cx_Oracle.connect(self._configHelper.get_oracledb_connection_string())
cursor = self._connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('Set role role_name identified by xyz')
results = list(cursor.fetchall())
```

When I tried this I got "interface error: not a query". But it does work fine when I run it using SQL Developer, so there is no error in the query.

I also tried

```
cursor.callproc('Set role role_name identified by xyz')
```

and it says invalid char at line 1 column 11

can someone please guide me on what is the right way to execute this in Python

Answer (score 1):

My code was wrong, I had used

`results = cursor.fetchall()`

thinking I would check for the status and it was this statement which was causing the problem. So the solution is

`self._connection = cx_Oracle.connect(self._configHelper.get_oracledb_connection_string())
cursor = self._connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('Set role role_name identified by xyz')`

Answer (score 0):

Try executing a PL/SQL block with execute immediate:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'Set role role_name identified by xyz';
end;
```

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, I had

results = list(cursor.fetchall())

which was complaining that it wasnt a query and I thought it was cursor.execute